Sentinel-2 QA60 band missing?
When performing cloud masking for Sentinel-2 images using QA60 band, I found that after February 2024, the QA bands of Sentinel-2 images are all "masked".
In this case, I can't perform cloud masking for Sentinel-2 images.


I'm using the cloud masking example code "Sentinel2 Cloud And Shadow" on GEE, and I also found that after 2021, this code will produce all masked images. Is this related to some bands or some dataset missing?

According to the EE Data Catalogue, that data is missing from Feb 2022 (until recently):

QA60 is a bitmask band that contained rasterized cloud mask polygons until Feb 2022, when these polygons stopped being produced. Starting in February 2024, legacy-consistent QA60 bands are constructed from the MSK_CLASSI cloud classification bands.

I would suggest that you try Cloud Score+. It works a lot better than QA60 ever did. Here's the usage example from that page:
// Harmonized Sentinel-2 Level 2A collection.
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED');

// Cloud Score+ image collection. Note Cloud Score+ is produced from Sentinel-2
// Level 1C data and can be applied to either L1C or L2A collections.
var csPlus = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/CLOUD_SCORE_PLUS/V1/S2_HARMONIZED');

// Region of interest.
var ROI = ee.Geometry.Point(-119.9087, 37.4159);

// Use 'cs' or 'cs_cdf', depending on your use case; see docs for guidance.
var QA_BAND = 'cs_cdf';

// The threshold for masking; values between 0.50 and 0.65 generally work well.
// Higher values will remove thin clouds, haze & cirrus shadows.
var CLEAR_THRESHOLD = 0.60;

// Make a clear median composite.
var composite = s2
    .filterBounds(ROI)
    .filterDate('2023-01-01', '2023-02-01')
    .linkCollection(csPlus, [QA_BAND])
    .map(function(img) {
      return img.updateMask(img.select(QA_BAND).gte(CLEAR_THRESHOLD));
    })
    .median();

// Sentinel-2 visualization parameters.
var s2Viz = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 2500};

Map.addLayer(composite, s2Viz, 'median composite');
Map.centerObject(ROI, 11);

